# CLick UL tag using Selenium WEBdriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I have a HTML code as mentioned below with UL tag, and I wanted to click the UL tag Manage -> Channel using Selenium Webdriver. To do that I have written the below code in java but it is not working, infact no error is throwing but page is getting opened. Please help.

HTML

```
<ul class="adb-primary_nav--items adb-layout-default">
                <li class="adb-primary_nav--item">
                    <a class="adb-primary_nav--link en" href="../">
                        <img class="adb-primary_nav--image" src="https://d33na3ni6eqf5j.cloudfront.net/marketplace_logo/img1474715110198223685.png?7ef040694410736c21450bea763bb661" alt="Vodafone Group">

                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="adb-primary_nav--item">
                    <a class="adb-primary_nav--link" id="myapps" href="../myapps">
                        MyApps
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="adb-primary_nav--item">
                    <a class="adb-primary_nav--link" id="shop" href="../home">
                        Marketplace
                    </a>
                </li>

                    <li class="adb-primary_nav--item"><a class="adb-primary_nav--link" id="developer" href="../cms/home">Developer</a></li>

                <li class="adb-primary_nav--item js-drainable-menu">
                    <div class="adb-context_menu adb-js-context_menu">
                        <a id="manage" class="adb-context_menu--trigger adb-js-context_menu--trigger adb-primary_nav--link admin-item selected" role="button" tabindex="0">Manage</a>
                        <div class="adb-container adb-context_menu--menu adb-js-context_menu--menu" role="menu">
                            <ul class="adb-stack">


                                    <li class="adb-stack--item"><a class="adb-link__option adb-stack--item_content" href="../corporate/home">Corporate</a></li>


                                    <li class="adb-stack--item"><a class="adb-link__option adb-stack--item_content selected" href="./marketplace">Channel</a></li>



                                    <li class="adb-stack--item"><a class="adb-link__option adb-stack--item_content" id="account" href="../account/home">Account</a></li>

                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>

                <li class="adb-primary_nav--item adb-primary_nav--item__right">
                    <div class="adb-context_menu adb-js-context_menu" data-placement="right">
                        <a class="adb-context_menu--trigger adb-js-context_menu--trigger adb-primary_nav--link" role="button" tabindex="0">testchannel user</a>
                        <div class="adb-container adb-context_menu--menu adb-js-context_menu--menu" role="menu">
                            <ul class="adb-stack">

                                    <li class="adb-stack--item">
                                        <a class="adb-link__option adb-stack--item_content" id="myProfile" href="../profiles/5944276">My Profile</a>
                                    </li>


                                    <li class="adb-stack--item">
                                        <a class="adb-link__option adb-stack--item_content" id="myCompany" href="../companies/219288">My Company</a>
                                    </li>

                                <li class="adb-stack--item">
                                    <a class="adb-link__option adb-stack--item_content" id="mySettings" href="../settings">My Settings</a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="adb-stack--item">
                                    <a class="adb-link__option adb-stack--item_content" id="logout" href="../logout">Logout</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
```

Java Code

```
Configuration_file var = new Configuration_file();

        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\gur29175\\workspace\\SAAS\\jars\\chromedriver.exe");

        WebDriver firefox_dri = new ChromeDriver();
        firefox_dri.get(var.env_URL + "/home");
        firefox_dri.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30,TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        firefox_dri.findElement(By.cssSelector("a:(*'Manage'*)")).click(); 
        firefox_dri.findElement(By.cssSelector("a:(*'Channel'*)")).click();
```

Comment: Can you share the URL link ?

Answer (score 0):

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@id='manage']")).click()
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//ul[@class='adb-stack']/li[2]")).click()

Answer (score 0):

In case of a listbox, you need to get the list of elements and iterate over it to choose the required element.
Please share the screenshot of the page with dropdowns. Will be able to guide you with the code.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace

```
firefox_dri.findElement(By.cssSelector("a:(*'Manage'*)")).click(); 
firefox_dri.findElement(By.cssSelector("a:(*'Channel'*)")).click();
```

with

```
firefox_dri.findElement(By.linkText("Channel")).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it

```
//ul[@class='adb-stack']/li[@class='adb-stack--item']/a[contains(text(),'Corporate')].click();
```